# Load external url /count /highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

What I need is load an external url page in --div-- then count and highlight specific word on that loaded external page and write the count to main page.
Please help.

Example of webpage layout:

With : 2  |  this : 2

-------Load external page ----
I need help with coding this page.
With your help I can do this.
Please help me.
Thank you.
Mari.
------End of external page -----

Answer (score 0):

You can't load an External URL! If the 'external' page is on your server you can load it with `jQuery` and if not you must write a script with `PHP` that loads you the external page and the with jQuery you can put it on your page.